# Yii model to array?

Tags: arrays, model, yii

How can I convert the result of `Trips::model()->findAll()` to an array?

Comment: About to be implemented https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/531

Answer (score 34):

I'm going on the assumption here that you only need to retrieve just the bare arrays, and not any associated model objects.

This will do it:

```
$model = Trips::model();
$trips = $model->getCommandBuilder()
               ->createFindCommand($model->tableSchema, $model->dbCriteria)
               ->queryAll();
```

This is like the `Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl')->queryAll();` examples, except:

- It'll ask the model for the table name; you won't need to write the table name in both the model and the query.
- You can call [scoping](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) functions on `$model` first, eg.
  `$model = Trips::model()->short()->destination('Austin, TX');`
  Doing this means you can use the model's existing query shortcuts, instead of putting them in the query directly.

In contrast, the `$trips = Trips::model()->findAll();` (using foreach) is a bit wasteful, in that you're pulling the rows from the database, setting up a bunch of objects, and then throwing them all away. It'll work fine for small result sets, but I wouldn't use that if you're looking at a long list of Trips.

**Caveat:**
If this is just a quick prototype, though, by all means use the `createCommand()` or findAll()-and-loop examples.

Comment: Quick warning for anyone using this approach: Upon changing the select in the $model->dbCriteria to only get the columns I needed.. this affected (and stripped other attributes from) all standard $model->find() calls in the same request. Particularly hard bug to find.

Comment: @Arth: I'm confused; are you saying you're modifying `$model->dbCriteria` directly before calling?

Comment: I am too, I wrote that a long time ago! I guess I must have!

Answer (score 27):

This is the right way to do, it follows Yii conventions

```
$trips = Trips::model()->findAll();
$arr = array();
foreach($trips as $t)
{
    $arr[$t->id] = $t->attributes;
}
```

This is used when you have complex queries, those you find difficult to create with Yii conventions.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl')->queryAll();
```

For example, when you need to pass all the data from the model to an array. You cannot pass it directly as it does pass some ActiveRecord data information that you don't need.

Comment: I would not recommend using the first solution you provided. findAll method creates model object for every row and then populates it's attributes property. It is unnecessary operation because you just need raw data from the database. createCommand is preferable.

Comment: @vooD I disagree, I think this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

This is same.

```
$array = CHtml::listData(Trips::model()->findAll(), 'trip_id', 'trip_name');
```

Comment: The `Trips::model()->findAll()` in combination with `listData()` (which is doing a foreach over the models) is a bit wasteful, in that you're pulling the rows from the database, setting up a bunch of objects, and then throwing them all away.

Answer (score 6):

Easy and simple way: I use [listData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) method to make array to dropdown menus, and I think this will help you.. check this example:

code:

```
<?php 
     /*you can use here any find method you think 
     proper to return your data from db*/
     $models = Trips::model()->findAll();

     // format models resulting using listData     
     $tripsArray = CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'name');    

     print_r($tripsArray);
?>
```

output:

```
array(
 '1'=>'trip1',
 '2'=>'trip2',
 '3'=>'trip3',
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$model = Trips::model()->findAll(); 
$arr = CHtml::listData($model, 'trip_id', 'trip_name');
var_dump($arr);
```

CHtml::listData() will return an array value.

Comment: The `$trips = Trips::model()->findAll()` in combination with `listData()` (which is doing a foreach over the models) is a bit wasteful, in that you're pulling the rows from the database, setting up a bunch of objects, and then throwing them all away.

Answer (score 4):

You can create collections **CMap** continue to work with her

```
$collections = new CMap();
foreach (YourModel::model()->findAll(['index' => 'id']) as $key => $row) {
   $collections->add($key,$row->attributes);
}
var_dump($collections ->toArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can do this:

```
$trips = Trips::model()->findAll();
$arr = array();
foreach($trips as $t)
{
    $arr[$t->id] = $t->attributes;
}
```

I'm assuming you have the attribute 'id' as your model's primary key.

Comment: ahem, don't forget to check whether $trips is empty or not :D

Comment: the $trips will always returning an array, foreach each will not returning error even iteration is an empty array.

Comment: ZaQ - if findAll() returns an empty array, checking for empty before using foreach is a waste.

Answer (score 3):

i use `$array = CJSON::decode(CJSON::encode($model));` to convert $model to $array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this.

```
$Trips::model()->findAll(array('index'=>'trip_id'));
if(count($Trips)>0)
            {                   
                $TripsArrayList=array();
                foreach($Tripsas as $singleTrip)
                {                   
                    $TripsArrayList[]=array('trip_id'=>$singleTrip->trip_id,'name'=>$singleTrip->name);         
                }                   
            }
```

Your output will be

```
Array
    (
      [0] => Array
                 (
                   [trip_id] => 1
                   [name] => Nashik
                 )
      [1] => Array
                 (
                   [trip_id] => 2
                   [name] => Puna
                 ) 
      [2] => Array
                 (
                   [trip_id] => 3
                   [name] => Mumbai
                 ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cats = Category::model()->findAll();
$count_cats = count($cats);
if($count_cats > 0){
    $arr_category = array();
    foreach($cats as $cat)
        array_push($arr_category,$cat->attributes);
}
print_r($arr_category);
```

-> result

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cat_id] => 2
        [title] => Đương đại
        [title_full] => Đương đại
        [desc] => 
        [alias] => duong-dai
        [p_id] => 0
        [type] => 1
        [status] => 1
        [sort_order] => 2
        [selected] => 0
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [cat_id] => 164
        [title] => Nhiệt đới
        [title_full] => Nhiệt đới
        [desc] => 
        [alias] => nhiet-doi
        [p_id] => 0
        [type] => 1
        [status] => 1
        [sort_order] => 0
        [selected] => 0
    )
[...])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from your question that you want all the attributes, a more compact solution to give you all attributes hashed by id, you can use CActiveRecord's 'attributes' pseudoproperty as follows:

```
CHtml::listData(Trips::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'attributes')
```

Answer (score 2):

In yii2 you can use asArray()

```
$someArray = Sometable::find()->select(['id', 'name', 'role'])->asArray()->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DAO for arrays

```
$array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl')->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't used CHtml::listData for this. It has to be used for other purposes.
There is an **index** property of CDbCriteria which is suitable for you requirement.

```php
//1st option
Trips::model()->findAll(array('index'=>'trip_id'));

//2nd option
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->index = 'trip_id';
Trips::model()->findAll($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simply:

```
$trips = Trips::model()->findAll();

$trips_array = CJSON::decode(CJSON::encode($trips));
```

**Note:** This is not good way but returns array

Comment: [CJSON](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON) is Yii Core Class