# get foreign table records in listData function

Tags: php, yii

This is YII framework and i have following table : tbl_banner_location_type

```
bannerLocationTypeId(PK)    bannerLocationId(FK)    bannerTypeId(FK)
1                           1                       2
2                           2                       5
3                           1                       6
```

Now i have bannerLocationId's value as input. i.e. 1
I want all banner type values which comes from different table.
I have tried below code but getting error: **Property BannerLocationType.$data->bannerType->value" is not defined.**

```
$data = BannerLocationType::model()->findAll('bannerLocationId=:bannerLocationId', 
              array(':bannerLocationId'=>(int) $_POST['bannerLocationId']));

$data = CHtml::listData($data,'bannerTypeId','$data->bannerType->value');   
echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>''),CHtml::encode('- - Select - -'),true);
foreach($data as $value=>$name)
{
    echo CHtml::tag('option',
               array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
}
```

I know i can get it's value by following way but i want array.

```
$obj= BannerLocationType::model()->findByPk($id); 
$obj->bannerType->value;
```

Please help.

Comment: What is you question exactly? Perhaps you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435886/yii-model-to-array

Comment: i want array but based on bannerTypeId, it's value should come from BannerType model.

Comment: give more information... the structure of bannerType table along with the relation you have defined between banner_location_type and banner_type tables in banner_location_type model

Answer (score 4):

Ohhh... Issue is fixed..That was so basic.. My poor YII knowledge.

I have changed

```
  $data = CHtml::listData($data,'bannerTypeId','$data->bannerType->value');
```

with

```
$data = CHtml::listData($data,'bannerTypeId','bannerType.value');
```

Sorry friends if my question was unclear. But i was not sure how do i represent this issue.