# Yii SQL query from CDbCriteria

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

I have a model with complex relations which uses CDbCriteria for filtering data to be viewed in CGridView.
I need to be able to export the filtered results also as a CSV file. 
For that, using ActiveRecords is too resource consuming (20000+ records), so it would be a lot faster to use CDbCommand to get the same results and export them.

The problem is, I cannot find a way to get the raw sql query that ActiveRecords builds from CDbCriteria. 
Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: I think you may find the answer you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4577768/287030

Answer (score 0):

The [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) on building queries is pretty good.